# How to grep files that has different letters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have thousands of files in a directory that are called: `abc.txt srr.txt eek.txt abb.txt` and etc. I want to grep only those files that has different last two letters. Example:

Good output: `abc.txt eek.txt` 
Bad output: `ekk.txt dee.txt`. 
Here is what I am trying to do:

`#!/bin/bash
ls -l directory |grep .txt`

It greps every file that has `.txt` in it.

How do I grep files that has two different last letters?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Where do these files come from and why do you need that particular subset? To me it sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that you could instead circumvent by a better design of the larger system!

Comment: It's nothing special, just me playing around with grep. I've created thousands of files with `touch` in one directory and I want to move them to another directory. But I only want to move those files that have different last two letters. Example: `abc.txt aab.txt`. Bad example: `abb.txt err.txt` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with `find` to list the `*.txt` files, and `grep` to filter out the ones that have the last two letters the same (using a backreference):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | grep -v '\(.\)\1\.txt$'
```

It essentially picks up a character then immediately tries to back-reference it before `.txt`, and `-v` provides a reverse match leaving only files that do not have the same last two characters.

**UPDATE**: To move the found files you can chain `mv` to the command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | grep -v '\(.\)\1\.txt$' | xargs -i -t mv {} DESTINATION
```

Comment: Looks good. Maybe you call tell me on how to use this command to move those files into another directory (that is already created)?

Comment: Do we need those extra backslashes in `grep`?  Won't just `grep -v "\(.\)\1\.txt$"` do?

Comment: @codeforester - fair point, it's an old habit of mine to escape every backslash when typing in double quotes as some shells (programming languages, too) will evaluate the character following a backslash as 'special' whether it is or not. Should've gone with single quotes, tho, but I already had the `find` part typed out and I hate mixing string literals so I went along with it ;) To be safe, single quotes are probably the way to go anyway, so I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to parse the result of `ls` (read this [doc](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to understand why).  Here is what you could do in pure Bash, without using any external commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

shop -s nullglob                                                  # make sure glob yields nothing if there are no matches
for file in *.txt; do                                             # grab all .txt files
  [[ -f $file ]] || continue                                      # skip if not a regular file
  last6="${file: -6}"                                             # get the last 6 characters of file name
  [[ "${last6:1:1}" != "${last6:2:1}" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file" # pick the files that match the criteria
  # change printf to mv "$file" "$target_dir" above if you want to move the files
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seem to accomplish what I wanted by using this:

`ls -l |awk '{print $9}' | grep -vE "(.).?\1.?\."`

- `awk '{print $9}'` prints only the `.txt` files
- `grep -vE '(.).?\1.?\.'` filters any names where the three characters before the period are not unique: `aaa.txt`, `aab.txt`, `aba.txt` and `baa.txt` are all filtered.